# Android Manifest Merge issue - Removing google ads gradle dependency doesn't remove its AndroidManifest.xml nodes

Tags: android, android-manifest, android-gradle-3.0, manifest-merging

I am having two product flavors in the project (1) free (2) pro

I am including google ads library only to the free product flavor as below

```
freeCompile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-ads:11.4.2'
```

Now I want to replace it with another ad library. I am trying to remove this dependency but it doesn't remove the library completely and gives me an error as below. Hence it doesn't let me build the project.

[image]

The screenshot is of AndroidManifest.xml from the `app\build\intermediates\manifests\full\free\debug`. Also I have not manually added these two activities (`com.google.android.gms.ads.AdActivity` & `com.google.android.gms.ads.purchase.InAppPurchaseActivity`) to the main AndroidManifest.xml.

**What I have tried to remove these two activities from AndroidManifest.xml is**

1. Clean, Build, Rebuild
2. Restart Android Studio
3. Invalidate caches / Restart Android Studio
4. Changing the project flavors & cleaning.
5. Removing the dependency from the Android Studio 'Project Structure'

But nothing seems to be working. How can I get rid of these errors and build my project?

Answer (score 0):

After a day long hassle, I managed to fix it using this official Android guildeline - [Merge Multiple Manifest Files](https://developer.android.com/studio/build/manifest-merge.html#attribute_markers)

`tools:node="remove"` did the trick.

I have manually removed those two activities that are the part of google sdk. Here is what I have added to the main `AndroidManifest.xml`

```
 <activity
     android:name="com.google.android.gms.ads.AdActivity"
     android:configChanges="keyboard|keyboardHidden|orientation|screenLayout|uiMode|screenSize|smallestScreenSize"
     android:exported="false"
     android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Translucent"
     tools:node="remove" />

 <activity
     android:name="com.google.android.gms.ads.purchase.InAppPurchaseActivity"
     android:theme="@style/Theme.IAPTheme"
     tools:node="remove" />
```

Hope it helps to someone.